# Details on molybdenum bioavailability in milk?

Tags: nutrition, milk, meal-replacement

There have been reports of molybdenum in milk [since before 1951](http://www.journalofdairyscience.org/article/S0022-0302(51)91818-8/abstract). However, supposedly "[there [is] no data on bioavailability in cow's milk](https://www.nrv.gov.au/nutrients/molybdenum)" after all these years. Most sources I find claim milk contains somewhere on the order of 50 μg/L. I'm having troubles finding more detail. Mostly I'm curious about my daily intake, and possible cheap but still mostly healthy meal replacements for lazy days.

How much molybdenum can I expect (as a low ball estimate) to count towards the [daily RDA of 45 μg](http://lpi.oregonstate.edu/infocenter/minerals/molybdenum/) from the about 35 μg in three cups of milk?

**Update:**

Perhaps the best way to answer this is to find out in what compounds the molybdenum are in in milk and see if there's any details on those compounds' bio-availability. I know they said the nutrient fed to the cows to increase the molybdenum content was ammonium molybdate, [which, along with sodium molybdate and potassium molybdate, should be bioavailable (along with most soluble molybdenum sources)](http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/pub/1136.htm). The Soylent discussion site (which is oddly appropriate to why I'm asking), [has other citings on their bio-availability listings](http://discourse.soylent.me/t/bioavailability-of-different-nutrient-forms/2830) which confirm this. If I find an answer, I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Diet.com](http://www.diet.com/g/molybdenum) suggests that molybdenum sources in food are between 57% and 88% efficient in absorption rates nutritionally, and additionally lists milk content as 4.9 μg per cup, which is much lower than the suggestions elsewhere. This may be a good lower bound for calculation. However, remember that the [tolerable upper limit for adults is considered to be 0.6 mg of molybdenum](http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/pub/1136.htm), according to the European Food Safety Authority as of 2000. Alternatively, Diet.com listed it as 2 mg.

Answer (score 2):

In [Dietary Reference Intakes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK222301/) by Institute of Medicine (US) Panel on Micronutrients we can read that RDA for adult men and women is 45 μg/day. The average dietary intake of molybdenum by adult men and women is 109 and 76 μg/day, respectively.

Biego and his coworkers<sup>[1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK222301/)</sup> in 1998 reported an average molybdenum concentration of 4 μg/L in human milk with stage of lactation not reported and much higher concentrations of molybdenum in cow's milk (50 μg/L, as does soymilk) and infant formula, however as you suggested - the data on the bioavailability of molybdenum in cow milk and infant formulas are not available.

How much it's per cup of milk - it can really vary on milk, however [Diet.com](http://www.diet.com/g/molybdenum) suggest it's around 4.9μg.

---

References:

- [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK222301/): Biego GH, Joyeux M, Hartemann P and Debry G, 1998. [Determination of mineral contents in different kinds of milk and estimation of dietary intake in infants.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10211184) Food Additives and Contaminants, 15, 775-781.